# Run time Data Form!

Tags: silverlight-4.0

i have a table which contains details of the form contents , here are the details

InputType ( value = Text / Radio / CheckBox , .... )

IsRequired ( True/False)

OrderedAnswers ( contain options available for Radio / checkbox  )

....

what i want is ,

make a page at run time which contains respective controls and the page submits the values of each control to the service .

at this point i have created the dataform , but cant define datatemplate dynamically so that i could add stackpanel to it and in the stackpanel i shall add the controls(based on the value). can you provide some code which shall create datatemplate dynamically and items to it ?

thanks

Jamal.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you want to add the stackpanel with controls to a particular property (in ria with a Silverlight DataForm)

first capture the event `AutoGeneratingField`i.e.

```
this.myDataForm.AutoGeneratingField +=new EventHandler<DataFormAutoGeneratingFieldEventArgs>(AutoGeneratingFieldHandler);
```

then in the event handler

```
void AutoGeneratingFieldHandler(object sender, DataFormAutoGeneratingFieldEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.PropertyName=="myPropertyNameWithCustomField")
  {
     StackPanel pnl = new StackPanel();
     pnl.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
     ComboBox cbo = new ComboBox();
     //setup binding to base
     Binding b = new Binding("myPropertyNameWithCustomField") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
     cbo.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, b);
     //add the combo to the stackpanel
     pnl.Children.Add(cbo);
     //replace the autogenerated content with the stackpanel
     e.Field.Content=pnl;
     e.Field.IsRequired=true;
  }
}
```

This should get you started setting up a DataForm with custom controls.